# Average calls per day in MS Access 2010

Tags: sql, select, ms-access-2010

I'm a receptionist keeping track of incoming calls in MS-Access 2010. The table has Date column. I can get count of calls per day but am having trouble with SQL to get average calls per day.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your table has one record per call, you can use a query like this, just replace the table and field names:

```
SELECT Avg(TotalCalls.DailyCalls) AS AverageCalls
FROM
(
    SELECT MyTable.MyDateField, Count(MyTable.MyDateField) AS DailyCalls
    FROM MyTable
    WHERE MyDate > #1-Feb-2017# AND MyDate <= #28-Feb-2017#
    GROUP BY MyTable.MyDateField
) AS TotalCalls
```

This won't take into account days that have no calls, just the ones that do.  The WHERE clause is optional, but you might want to use that to pick a specific date range.

Comment: Beautiful.  That is almost exactly what I've been working with.  My error was in trying to use GROUP BY in the last line where you used AS.